# changing movieclip properties, the alpha of it, inside of multiple movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a movieclip that's inside another movieclip which is also inside of another movieclip

SniperGun.Sniper.SniperScope.MC_ScopeEdge.

i set the alpha of MC_ScopeEdge to 50% of the color white but when i run my flash app it turns to full white, not semi-transparent white. but when i change the alpha to 0% it shows a completely transparent white movieclip.

i also tried placing a code that will change the alpha of the movieclip

```
ScopeEdgeColorEffect();
function ScopeEdgeColorEffect():void{
    stop();
    MC_ScopeEdge.alpha = 50;
}
```

but still the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid values for alpha are 0 (fully transparent) to 1 (fully opaque).
Try alpha = 0.5 for semi-transparent.

Comment: scratch that it worked perfectly! i just had to remove some codes that overwrites yours! BIG THANKS!